# Use Scala val as compile-time constant in Java

Tags: java, scala, constants

I would like to use a `val` in a Scala `object` as a compile-time constant in Java (specifically in a switch). My code looks like this:

```
class Scala {} // in case it matters, there is a class of the same name
object Scala {
    val foo = "foo"
}

class Java {
    void switchIt(String on) {
        switch (on) {
            case Scala$.MODULE$.foo: // doesn't compile because foo isn't a field
            case Scala$.MODULE$.foo(): // doesn't compile because foo() isn't a constant
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware of the following questions but none solves my problem:

- [Scala Reflection : why getMethods can return the val members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766311/scala-reflection-why-getmethods-can-return-the-val-members/29767209#29767209) - explains that a `val` gets compiled into a method
- [Use Scala constants in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861442/use-scala-constants-in-java) - the answer suggests calling the generated method
- [Scala: Compile time constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195171/scala-compile-time-constants) - suggests using `final val` to create compile-time constants; however, it is not clear on whether Java sees the result as a compile-time constant and doesn't appear to work in my case

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not to use `if ... else`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin I could use if/else. I could also convert it to PHP.